# Why does using "const data = require("./data.json");" make the startStop function stop working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a stopwatch app that takes in some data such as your name and Id number before it starts:

```
//define vars to hold time values
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

//define vars to hold display value

let displayseconds = 0;
let displayminutes = 0;
let displayhours = 0;

let interval = null;
let status = "stopped";



//stopwatch function (logic to detiermine when to increment value)
function stopWatch(){
    seconds++;
    //Logic to determien when to inciment next value
    if(seconds/60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if(minutes/60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    if(seconds < 10){
        displayseconds = "0" +seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayseconds = seconds;
    }
    if(minutes < 10){
        displayminutes = "0" +minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayminutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayhours = "0" +hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayhours = hours;
    }

    //Display updated time value
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayhours + ":" + displayminutes + ":" + displayseconds

}

function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started"
    }
    else{
        first.value = "";
        last.value = "";
        id.value = "";
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped"
        reset()
    }
}

function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
}

function dbwrite(){

    let user = {
        first: "Thatcher",
        last: "Pacholl",
        id: 730626
    };

// STEP 2: Adding new data to users object
    users.push(user);

// STEP 3: Writing to a file
    fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data), err => {

        // Checking for errors
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Done writing"); // Success
    });
}
```

but when I add:

```
const data = require("./data.json");
```

to the top so that I can acess and write data this function stops working:

```
function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started"
    }
    else{
        first.value = "";
        last.value = "";
        id.value = "";
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped"
        reset()
    }
}
```

in my HTML code this is what starts and stops the stopwatch so I need it but I also need to be able to retrieve that data from the entry fields, what can I do to fix this? For reference here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Stopwatch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="topnav">
            <a><img src="images/C.png" id="logo" width="180" height=auto></a>
            <a href="#home"><n>Home</n></a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="time" id="display">
            00:00:00
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <input id="first" class="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name:">
            <input id="last" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name:">
            <input id="id" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Id Number:" style="width: 150px" >
            <button id="startStop" onclick="startStop()">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const data = require("./data.json");` is something that would only work inside of nodejs, not inside of a browser.  And `document.getElementById()` is something that would only work inside of a browser so those two pieces of code can't be mixed together.  You need to be aware of where your code is running and write it for the appropriate environment.

Comment: So what could be a solution to this? Im new to Javascript and HTML so I dont exactly know what to do

Comment: Well, if `data.json` is a file on your server, you cannot directly load that into a web page.  The web page is running in some user's browser.  It cannot access files directly on your server - they are across the internet behind some hosting firewall.  You can either programmatically insert that data into the web page on your server as it is being sent to the user's browser (HTML templates on your server are often used to do this) or you can make an Ajax request from your web page's Javascript to ask the server to fetch data.json for you and the server can then get that data for the web page.

Comment: And, there are likely several other options too.  I don't' really understand enough of your root problem you're trying to solve or what's in data.json to know what the best overall architecture would be.